# CoreFoundation.h' file not found when active scheme is the device

Tags: iphone, ios6, core-foundation

I wanted to update an old app for the ios6 and retina 5 inch!
The app works fine on simulator but when setting the active scheme as my device it fails. Trying to fix the problem in two hours and no luck! Any tips?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Projects->Target->Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries, and make sure the CoreFoundation.framework is there.

Comment: and if it is already there then remove it once and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

SET Always Search User Paths = YES worked for med